# Users get the latitude and longitude values with GPS

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

Previously, I get the user's latitude and longitude using GPS. But Google had to adapt think about it. I do not take positions on Android 6.0. How do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if I get you right: You have a working solution for getting the gps-position for android below M?

Have you considered the new [runtime-permission-system](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)?